# .htaccess issues with unicode characters - need a redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, unicode

I am getting a number of 404s in WMT from URLs that I cannot seem to handle in .htaccess with redirects.

The main culprits end with a number of variants that appear to be Unicode characters:

The first 3 trail the final/ where as the fourth one precedes it /.

- `MyArticleLocation/%20%E2%80%A8`
- `MyArticleLocation/%C2%A0`
- `MyArticleLocation/%C2%A0`
- `MyArticleLocation%E2%80%A8/`

---

I have tried a number of redirects and think that this needs to be managed with a rewrite rather than redirect.

Would this work?

```
RewriteRule ^(/%C2%A0|%E2%80%A8/|/%20%E2%80%A8)$ / [L,R=301]
```

The existing code 'as is' below:

```
#BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModulp>

# END WordPress
```

Also, how would it be fettled with the code above?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule just **below RewriteBase line**:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)[\x20\xe2\xc2] /$1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Apache `mod_rewrite` lets you match those `%` hex characters using `\x` notation.